# Как изменить ссылку стандартной записи (поста) в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, url, чпу

Есть сайт с одним стандартным типом поста ("записи") и несколькими кастомными ("вафельки" и "лыжные палки"). Когда я открываю на сайте раздел "вафельки", то ссылка имеет вид [https://йуэрэлъ.ком/вафельки/](https://%D0%B9%D1%83%D1%8D%D1%80%D1%8D%D0%BB%D1%8A.%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8/). А когда открываю страницу записи про "Очень вкусные вафельки", то ссылка получается такая - [https://йуэрэлъ.ком/вафельки/очень-вкусные-вафельки](https://%D0%B9%D1%83%D1%8D%D1%80%D1%8D%D0%BB%D1%8A.%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8).
 
 
Аналогичная история с лыжными палками. 
 
 
А вот со стандартными записями всё на так. Ссылки получаются такие:
 
Много постов - [https://йуэрэлъ.ком/записи/](https://%D0%B9%D1%83%D1%8D%D1%80%D1%8D%D0%BB%D1%8A.%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8/)
 
Совсем один пост - [https://йуэрэлъ.ком/стандартная-постоянная-ссылка](https://%D0%B9%D1%83%D1%8D%D1%80%D1%8D%D0%BB%D1%8A.%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0)
 
А хочется - [https://йуэрэлъ.ком/записи/стандартная-постоянная-ссылка](https://%D0%B9%D1%83%D1%8D%D1%80%D1%8D%D0%BB%D1%8A.%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0)
 
Как это так сделать?

Главная - front-page.php
 
Записи - home.php с постоянной ссылкой "/записи/" 
 
Вид permalink в настройках - /%postname/
 
Nginx. Гуглил - не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, чтобы изменить ссылку для дефолтных постов, то надо идти в админку и там менять permalink. 
Чтобы это не отразилось на остальных кастомных постах, то при регистрации нового вида постов необходимо указать следующее:

```
register_post_type('new-post-type', array(
    ...
    'rewrite' => array( 'with_front'=> false ),
    ...
) );
```